# Convert object to array of strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing in my save method but here am getting as a list of array. but wanted to convert to set of string.

```
   mySys: $scope.stringArrayToObjectArray($scope.editmySystems,"name");
```

$scope.editmySystems holds value-

```
 0 :f
  id: svg
  name:"JASSI"
 1 :f
  id: svg2
  name:"JASSYY" 

 length: 2
```

So for conversion i wrote one function-

```
   $scope.stringArrayToObjectArray = function(stringArray, fieldName)   {
    var objectArr = [];
    angular.forEach(stringArray, function(singleString) {

        objectArr[fieldName]=singleString.name;

    });
    return objectArr;
};
```

currently objectArr is returning as-

```
     name: "JASON2"
```

Expected o/p- objectArr should return-

```
     name: ["JASSI","JASSYY"]
```

Please suggest

Comment: What do you expect `objectArr[fieldName]=singleString.name;` to do?

Comment: I have updated my post sir.. kindly advise

Comment: @zzzzBov, while that is clearly the bug, I'm not sure if there is any reason to bring quite that tone to the discussion. Clearly he tried and put forth some effort in solving it.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud, please re-read that question as just a question without sarcasm or malintent. It was meant as a serious question of expectations.

Comment: @MikePerrenoud , zzzzBov - Sir, I will improve quality of question in coming days. I am pretty new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could just use:

```
var stringArray = [{id: 'svg', name: 'JASSI'}];
var objectArr = [];

stringArray.map(function(item) {
    objectArr.push(item.name);
});

console.log(objectArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's close but you're setting indexes on an array which will be an object. Instead, simply append the field name.

```
$scope.stringArrayToObjectArray = function(stringArray, fieldName)   {
    var objectArr = [];

    angular.forEach(stringArray, function(singleString) {
        objectArr.push(singleString[fieldName]);
    });

    return objectArr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a callback which returns the wanted value of the key of the object.

> The **`map()`** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
function getValues(array, key) {
    return array.map(function (a) {
        return a[key];
    });
}

var data = [{ id: 'svg', name: 'JASSI' }, { id: 'svg2', name: 'JASSYY' }];

console.log(getValues(data, 'name'));
```